# Language update on apks

Tags: android, apktool, apksigner

I am owner of a smartphone with Android 8.1 onboard where many applications are lacking in the Italian language.
I have already created the working TWRP and the root with magisk.
I unpacked and decompilated the affected apk, updated the files on values-it, recompilated and signed with the testkey, but I realized that the applications are not installed because the manufacturing company has signed the apks with proprietary keys and not with testkey.
Any ideas on how to inject the files of my interest without having to necessarily sign the apk?

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall their app to install your modified version, but there's no guarantee that it will work correctly (some APIs only work conditionally to the key the app is signed with) and you won't get any update in the future either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. I have already tried and obviously it does not work because the applications are not signed with test keys but with proprietary keys.
Consider that I'm talking about system applications like systemUI, Settings and the framework itself. Is impossible to uninstall and replace them. Among other things, I tried to do it either through Rootexplorer (I set permissions correctly) or through TWRP, but when I reboot, I always crash the system because without the correct signature, the system applications is impossible to install it and are missing.